# I installed a module but it the code returns "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python

I installed a module named "tweepy" to use in my code using the following command: *pip install tweepy*, it installed perfectly like any other module I installed before the only problem is when I write: `import tweepy` at the top of my coding file, the code doesn't function and produces this error:
*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'*

**Notes:**

1. I checked the *lib* directory and the module exists there
2. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module a couple of times and the issue isn't resolved
3. I tried installing it using pip3, same issue

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Try and install the lib with pip3: "pip3 install tweepy"

Comment: did that and it didn't work

Comment: How do you launch the code?

Comment: If you are using JuPyter notebook, try restarting the kernel.

Comment: Im using visual studio code, I save the file then run the code.
not sure if that answers what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Try this command instead:

```
python3 -m pip install tweepy
```

Comment: didnt work unfortuently